# python optimization of target searching algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on optimizing some data search and looking for some suggestions as to the approach taken and best structure to use for the data.  The goal is to find a set of distinct matches in integer-sortable data whose difference is a given target value.  I've looked a bit in to finding the match count and list of matches separately, but am a bit lost on how best to combine the two approaches.  Any recommendations would be helpful!

Here's what I've put together so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

# Evaluator
# given a list of integer-sortable data
# find pairs whose difference is a given number

from collections import Counter


def pairs_diff_target(numbers, target):
  """Find pairs, ignoring duplicates and the 0 target."""
  if len(numbers) < 2 or target == 0:
    return None

  number_map = {}
  for i in numbers:
    number_map[i] = True

  pairs = []
  for i in numbers:
    pair = (i + target)
    if pair in number_map:
      pairs.append((pair, i))
      del number_map[i]

  return pairs

def duplicates_match_count(numbers, target):
  """Return a count of matches"""
  if len(numbers) < 2:
    return None

  # Use a counter to count occurrences
  counter = Counter()
  for number in numbers:
    counter[number] += 1

  if target == 0:
    # Return nC2 combinations
    return ((counter[number] * counter[number] - 1) // 2)
  else:
    matches = 0
    for number in numbers
      target_match = (number + target)
      matches += counter[number] * counter[target_match]
      del counter[number]
    return matches


def duplicates_match_list(numbers, target):
  """Return the actual list of matching elements"""
  if len(numbers) < 2:
    return None

  # Possible implementation better than n^2


if __name__ == "__main__":
  nums = [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,6]

  distinct_pairs = duplicates_match_count(nums, 0)
  # all 1,1 and 2,2 pairs
  assert len(distinct_pairs) == 60

  distinct_pairs = duplicates_match_count(nums, 1)
  # all 1,2 pairs and 2,3 pairs
  assert len(distinct_pairs) == 42

  distinct_pairs = duplicates_match_count(nums, 3)
  # (0,3), (3,6)
  assert len(distinct_pairs) == 2
```

Comment: i think  your problem is [similiar](https://www.spoj.com/problems/HACKRNDM/) to this and you can solve it in O(NLOGN) . few solution  [sol 1](https://github.com/lanhhoang/big-o/blob/cc5b2696f396d16a1fcdd9ee039f15f83c734c1f/week-06/day-12/in-class/hackrndm_hacking_random_number_generator.py) [sol 2](https://github.com/apopa57/spoj/blob/6f97ca93b7a44750c247168a4fa4c6d8eba8a6e4/hackrndm/hackrndm.py)

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list of pair repetitions and only compute the count of each pair rather than generating all of the instances immediately.    This should work in O(n) time:

```
from collections import Counter

def pairsWithDifference(target,numbers):
    counts = Counter(numbers)
    pairs  = [ (n,n+target,(c-0**target)*counts[n+target]) for n,c in counts.items() ]
    return [ pair for pair in pairs if pair[2] > 0 ]

nums = [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,6]
pd0 = pairsWithDifference(0,nums) # [(1, 1, 30), (2, 2, 30)] :: 30+30 = 60
pd1 = pairsWithDifference(1,nums) # [(1, 2, 36), (0, 1, 6), (2, 3, 6)] 36+6+6 = 48
pd2 = pairsWithDifference(2,nums) # [(1, 3, 6), (0, 2, 6)] 6+6 = 12
pd3 = pairsWithDifference(3,nums) # [(0, 3, 1), (3, 6, 1)] 1+1 = 2
```

You could then use this data to recreate the pairs lists as needed.

```
from functools import reduce
pairs0 = reduce(lambda a,p:a+[(p[0],p[1])]*p[2],pd0,[]) 
pairs1 = reduce(lambda a,p:a+[(p[0],p[1])]*p[2],pd1,[]) 
pairs2 = reduce(lambda a,p:a+[(p[0],p[1])]*p[2],pd2,[]) 
pairs3 = reduce(lambda a,p:a+[(p[0],p[1])]*p[2],pd3,[])
```

If you only need the number of pairs, the function can produce it directly (and faster):

```
def countPairDifference(target,numbers):
    counts = Counter(numbers)
    return sum([ (c-0**target)*counts[n+target] for n,c in counts.items() ])
```